# Highcharts Data Migration From Older Versions

Tags: highcharts, migration, upgrade

I've been asked by a client to help them migrate their older Highcharts to the most current release.  They are mainly using Highcharts v5.0.14 (Highcharts is currently v8.1.2), with a few older charts that are going back to v3.x and v4.x.  I have not gained access to any of their resources yet, so I cannot comment on specifics, such as what modules they are using.

Have there been any changes in data requirements, or formatting of the raw data, with any of the past releases?  Or has the data usage remained stable throughout all major releases?

I realize configurations and customizations have changed greatly since those older releases, but I'm more focused and interested in just the data right now, since that impacts the back-end servers.

I've tried to search for data migration documentation pertaining to older releases, but I have not been able to find anything.  Nor do I just want to assume that the data formats have remained constant.

Thanks greatly for any information that you can provide on past data migration concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure how about the 3 v. but for upper versions data structure is the same as it used to be, that means for basic charts:

- array of numbers:

  data: [1, 2, 3]
- array of arrays:

  data: [[x, y], [x,y], [x,y]]
- array of objects with specific data:

  data: [{x: number or string, y: number}]

Any other data format needs to be corrected by defining the keys: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys

What particularly has changed for each version you can find in the changelog: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/